# Can't get PDFBox CreatePDFA example to work - Color profile not found

Tags: pdfbox, color-profile

I'm trying to get the example for creating a PDF/A document with Apache PDFBox up an running ([CreatePDFA.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreatePDFA.java?view=markup)).

For this I copied the example class as is into a project module that includes a maven-dependency on PDFBox in version 2.0.0-RC3. I only changed the method signature and used a fixed font, filename and message instead of args[].

When trying to run the code I get an NPE in Line 107 because it cant't load the color profile (InputStream is null) When I check the included library in the project details I can see the resources folder, but it does not contain the expected file, namely "pdfa/sRGB Color Space Profile.icm".

[image: Screenshot of PDFBox resources in the project]

Unfortunately, google-ing the problem only turned up more references to always the same example implementation, but after a while I acutally found what seems to be the needed file on [apache.googlesource.com](https://apache.googlesource.com/pdfbox/+/trunk/examples/src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/pdfa)

I copied the file to our own resource directory and then used this line of code instead:

```
InputStream colorProfile = CreatePdfA.class.getResourceAsStream("/pdfa/sRGB Color Space Profile.icm");
```

This finally stopped the NPE - the file is apparently found - but now I get another exception which says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ICC Profile Data
```

Here, I'm stuck. I had hoped that this would work just out of the box, but it seems like I am missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: putting it into your own resource dir ist correct. But don't use the Google download, use the file from the source code download on the pdfbox site

Comment: here's the icc profile if you don't want to download the sources: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/pdfa/

Comment: Oops, I see now that your link goes to a svn mirror. However just a few days ago, I was able to create a servlet and I just copied the file to my resource directory. I wonder if something happened like that the icc profile was converted to ascii.

Comment: Just dowloaded the file you linked and it works. Maybe post an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: done. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You already answered one part of the problem yourself: put the file into your resource directory.

The second problem may be a bad repository mirror or a transfer problem (binary to ascii). Here's the official repository URL with the ICC profile from the example:
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/pdfa/